# Routing to an anchor tag from other pages in Nextjs project not functioning as expected in chromium browsers

Tags: reactjs, next.js, scroll, tailwind-css, chromium

I've been working on a NextJS project, and am experiencing a weird issue that I can't seem to find the solution to. So in chromium browsers (safari, firefox have no issues), when routing from a different page (or even when opening a link directly in a new tab), the page starts scrolling down and then just stops before it reaches the actual anchor. When clicking on the same anchor link (it's in the nav) from the same page it works perfectly.

I've tried at least 10 solutions, including removing lazyload from next/image elements, changing scroll behaviour of all links including a hash (thanks chatgpt) and many more, none seem to work.

Has anyone else had this issue? And if so, found any solutions? I really appreciate any help I can get here!